# convert ascii to integer like '\x01' inputs

Tags: python-2.7, integer, ascii

I get data from network in bytearray and I need to get integer value in bytearray[i]. It is ASCII and when I try to convert integer with int() I get exception. How can I try to convert '\x01' to get 1 in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord):

```
>>> ord('\x01')
1
```

or [`struct.unpack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('B', '\x01')
(1,)
>>> struct.unpack('2B', '\x01\x02')
(1, 2)
```

Comment: Actually I have tried ord() but I realized that I had used with wrong value, I see that in my python terminal history. Thanks.